# Accessing response in an AJAX CORS request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am trying to send an AJAX request to my spring backend. I am hitting the controller, and am successfully responding. I am new to javascript and AJAX, so I have hit a ceiling that I cannot get through. I am trying to call "done" on a successful callback, and am getting a very non-descriptive error. This is my console after I push "button"

```
clicked testAjax. js:3  
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :  product:1
```

I haven't created a product file, but when I go into it I get the object I am trying to send back on line 1 (the only line):

```
{"name":"Matthew","id":0}
```

My AJAX call is down below. How do I get the return object to enter my "done" function?

Also, what else am I doing wrong?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    var request = $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : ***The problem is not here, I am hitting the controller***
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: done,
        });
    function done(obj, status, jqXHR){
        alert("in success function");
        console.log(obj);
        $("li#pName").append("matthew");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting `dataType` to `jsonp`, but you are putting out straight json text, jsonp expects a function to be provided ie `someFn({"name":"Matthew","id":0})`

Since jquery automatically appends a random name for the callback function name if you do not provide one, you need to capture the `callback` GET variable and echo out the json text wrapped by a function call named by the name in the `callback` variable.

not familiar with spring but with php this would look something like

```
$fnName = $_GET["callback"];
echo $fnName."(".json_encode($someDataObj).")";
```

Change your backend to do something like that or change the `dataType` to `json`, so that it will parse straight json text.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I switched it to dataType: json and it works like I wanted it to. Is there a case (With a POST or more complicated calls) that I should prefer jsonp as the typical dataType?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2989921 jsonp is used when doing cross-domain requests when you do not have access to the backend of the domain to add like CORS headers.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a little hinky. Make sure you close the brackets properly too - I think that's what's getting you in trouble.

Here's the solution for using a anonymous function in the AJAX request:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  console.log("clicked");
  var request = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : ***The problem is not here, I am hitting the controller***
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (obj, status, jqXHR) {
      alert("in success function");
      console.log(obj);
      $("li#pName").append("matthew");
    }
  });
});
```

And here's the solution for when you want to use a separate function.

```
function done(obj, status, jqXHR) {
  alert("in success function");
  console.log(obj);
  $("li#pName").append("matthew");
}

$("button").click(function(){
  console.log("clicked");
  var request = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : ***The problem is not here, I am hitting the controller***
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: done
  });
});
```

Comment: this still wouldnt work as he has dataType as jsonp and he is only putting out json.

Comment: My JS skills are very suspect. I appreciate the help, I ended up making it an anonymous function that lives under "success".

Comment: *"Why don't you just use an anonymous function for success instead."* There's nothing wrong (and several things right) about using a separate, named function for the success handler.